# How to add a Property To a System Defined Class VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Lets just say i want to add a property to a class such as `DataGridViewColumn`.

Is there such a way to do this that i can cast these objects to lets say `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` This is currently what i am doing but is giving me an error.

I have my own class `DataGridViewColumn`

```
Public Class DataGridViewColumn
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn

Private Field As String
Public Property SomeField() As String
    Get
        Return Field
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Field = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Which is fine and works how i want it to. But when i go try something like this... It does not like it

```
Private Function gen(name As String) As DataGridViewColumn
        Select Case name
            Case "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
                Dim c2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                c2.Name = "tstColumn"
                c2.HeaderText = "Test Column"
                c2.ReadOnly = False
                Return c2
        End Select
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Is there any way to allow me to do this? I have also tried making a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` Class and inherting the `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` but nothing seems to work.

Error simply says Cannot be converted to type DataGridViewColumn even when i have my own DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Comment: I'd start by using a different class name than the one already used by NET.  Maybe `DataGridViewColumnEx`.  You will have other problems with that though because a TextBoxColumn is a different type than the basic DataGridViewColumn.  A generic would fix that

Comment: Okay thanks for that. But is there still some easier way to do this so i don't need to go through all the trouble just to add a simple property to the datacolumn?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you want to derive your own class from `DataGridViewColumn` and then have other classes that also inherit `DataGridViewColumn` somehow take on the members of your class.  The answer is no, that is not happening.  Classes that inherit `DataGridViewColumn` know only about members of `DataGridViewColumn`. One option for a hack might be to write a couple of extension methods to get and set the desired data in the column's `Tag` property. I can provide code in an answer if you're interested in that.

Comment: Note that in many, many cases data is not pushed directly into a DGV.  A DataSource is used such as a Datatable.  That already has a typed Field getter the form of an extension: `dr.Field(Of T)(index | Name)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured that I'd provide the answer I suggested in my comment regardless.  If you only want a single "property" then you could do this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace YourBusinessName.Windows.Forms

    Public Module DataGridViewColumnExtensions

        <Extension>
        Public Function GetField(source As DataGridViewColumn) As String
            Return TryCast(source.Tag, String)
        End Function

        <Extension>
        Public Sub SetField(source As DataGridViewColumn, value As String)
            source.Tag = value
        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```

You can then use those method like this:

```
Imports YourBusinessName.Windows.Forms

'...

Me.Column1.SetField("Hello World")

Dim fieldValue = Me.Column1.GetField()
```

If you wanted multiple "properties" then you could beef that up with a `Dictionary`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace YourBusinessName.Windows.Forms

    Public Module DataGridViewColumnExtensions

        <Extension>
        Public Function GetField1(source As DataGridViewColumn) As String
            Return GetField(source, "Field1")
        End Function

        <Extension>
        Public Function GetField2(source As DataGridViewColumn) As String
            Return GetField(source, "Field2")
        End Function

        Private Function GetField(source As DataGridViewColumn, propertyName As String) As String
            Dim fields = TryCast(source.Tag, Dictionary(Of String, Object))

            If fields Is Nothing OrElse Not fields.ContainsKey(propertyName) Then
                Return Nothing
            End If

            Return TryCast(fields(propertyName), String)
        End Function

        <Extension>
        Public Sub SetField1(source As DataGridViewColumn, value As String)
            SetField(source, "Field1", value)
        End Sub

        <Extension>
        Public Sub SetField2(source As DataGridViewColumn, value As String)
            SetField(source, "Field2", value)
        End Sub

        Private Sub SetField(source As DataGridViewColumn, propertyName As String, value As String)
            Dim fields = TryCast(source.Tag, Dictionary(Of String, Object))

            If fields Is Nothing Then
                fields = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                source.Tag = fields
            End If

            fields(propertyName) = value
        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```

You would still use those methods in the same way:

```
Imports YourBusinessName.Windows.Forms

'...

Me.Column1.SetField1("Hello World")

Dim fieldValue = Me.Column1.GetField2()
```

Note that methods that extend the `DataGridViewColumn` class can be called on an object of any type that is or inherits from `DataGridViewColumn`.

Comment: Thanks so much. This definitely helps out.